# Windows Network Drive Access is Slow From MacOS using SMB

Tags: windows, networking, macos, performance, smb

I can't seem to wrap my head around an issue I've been having with this so I thought it'd be a good idea to drop it here in case someone else has run into this problem in the past, or will eventually in the future.

I am sharing folders on my Windows PC for other users in our local network using a 1Gbit ethernet connection with a 1Gbit switch between all devices. I tested the access speed on all machines using OpenSpeedTest and it looks like everything is working fine here as I got speeds of around 950-980Mbit/s on all machines including the one running MacOS.

**File Sharing Setup:** The Windows machine I use to share the files has a pretty beefy setup by the way:

- Ryzen 9 3950X
- 64GB RAM
- Enough Fast SSD & HDD Storage

**Accessing Folders with many Files & Subfolders:** While I can easily access folders with huge numbers of subfolders and files from any of the other Windows PCs, the computer running MacOS will load some of these folders forever. I have setup the connection directly in Finder by using smb://192.168.178.5 and it does work fine if there's not many items inside of a folder.

**DaVinci Resolve Video Projects:** I first noticed this was an issue, when I tried to open any of my video projects in DaVinci Resolve Studio. While it loads any projects almost at native speed on any of my other Windows machines, the computer running MacOS takes about 30 seconds to load. If I click anywhere else during this time, it will completely freeze and the same thing happens when I am trying close the project.

**Blackmagic Disk Speed Test:** To make sure I was getting decent speeds over SMB, I also tried the Blackmagic Disk Speed tool, which showed me that I got around 88MB/s write and 106MB/s read speed. I was trying to access shared folders on both an SSD and HDD on the Windows machine and they both gave me almost similar results +-2MB/s here. I ran this test for a longer period of time and didn't notice any drops in performance. It doesn't hit the same numbers as the OpenSpeedTest tool here, but I could live with these numbers if it wasn't for the issues I mentioned above concerning folders not being shown at all and projects loading forever, etc. I am getting pretty similar speeds on my other Windows machines by the way, so speed itself doesn't seem to be the issue here.

**I tried the following things so far, but none of these have helped me with my issue:**

- I have checked my SMB version to make sure it's not falling back to any of the older versions and I can confirm my system is using the most up to date version 3.1.1
- I have disabled Network Store creating using the following terminal command:

  - *defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true*
- I have disabled IPv6 on the Windows PC sharing the files
- I have enabled NetBIOS over TCP/IP on the Windows PC sharing the files
- I have increased SMB credits on the Windows PC sharing the files using the following PowerShell command:

  - *set-smbserverconfiguration -smb2creditsmin 512 -smb2creditsmax 8192*
- I have created a nsmb.conf file inside of /etc/ with the following text added to the file and I also restarted my computer running MacOS afterwards

  - *[default]*
  - *signing_required = no*
  - *protocol_vers_map=6*
  - *port445=no_netbios*

I really hope someone can help me here as that problem.

TL;DR: The title says it all, pretty much. Couldn't make it any shorter, sorry! <3

Comment: Real-time antivirus/malware service could slow down some folders but you can exclude drives and type of files.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I solved my slow reading/writing problem just by turning off packet signing for SMB connections.

I've got the instructions here:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205926

I strangely had to restart the samba server for this to work.

Comment: He had already mentioned in his question (last bullet point) he already took those steps and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: He mentioned restarting the macOS, not the smb server. In my case I had to restart the server to take effect.

Comment: His SMB server is the Windows SMB server on the other end of the connection: Pointless to restart that as all the settings changes (SMB client) are done Mac-side and make no difference to the Windows SMB service. The changes only affect the type of connections (protocol versions/variants) the Mac makes to SMB fileshares and restarting the SMB client on the Mac insures that the Mac disconnects existing connections and re-establishes them with the new changes in effect.